# Do I need to set up my own OSRM server while using OSRM leaflet-routing-machine to display coordinates saved on DB snapped to road?

Tags: angular, leaflet, openstreetmap, osrm

Ok so in my angular app I am working on the frontend I have two dropdown in which I specify the city of departure and arrival and the backend uses an api that calculates the coordinates of this two inputs and saves them using leaflet and openstreet map I was able to display what I have stored in DB as a straight line which was not pretty so searching for a way to display them snapped to road I found OSRM leaflet-routing-machine which works great but every time I go to my component for visualizing my lines/paths the console shows this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nq5HJ.png) and while searching I found out by many others that you have to set up you own "set up instance of OSRM" but do I really need to do that just for displaying snaped to read lines ? Or is there a more convenient way? This is the code I am using for the demos servers I guess which I'm afraid will stop working at a given moment:

```
L.Routing.control({
      router: L.Routing.osrmv1({
        serviceUrl: `http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/`
      }),

      plan: L.Routing.plan(waypoints, {
        createMarker: (i, wp) => {
          return L.marker(wp.latLng, {
            draggable: false
          });
        }
      }),
      waypoints: waypoints,
      routeWhileDragging: false,
      addWaypoints : false, //disable adding new waypoints to the existing path
      show: false,


    }).addTo(this.map);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply just a quick follow up question say I set up an instance of OSRM on my pc and reference it on my code when I build my project and run my application will it work I mean as long as the pc I have set up my instance is on sorry if this sounds like a stupid or obvious one but this is the first time I am using OSRM and to set it up I have to work with docker which is something I haven't worked either so I'm new to many things in this case :')

Answer (score 0):

To whoever/whomever which one is the correct way to use has been struggling with finding an appropriate way to install an instance of OSRM in you machine/pc/server I will refer with the link that helped me out installing it on my pc(windows 11 OS) and successfully using it without displaying the warning on the console:

https://phabi.ch/2020/05/06/run-osrm-in-docker-on-windows/

side note you need to have Docker Desktop installed on you pc make the right configuration to docker desktop and as the link above suggests: Add the path to the docker binary to your system environment’s path variable. Hope this helps it sure helped me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).